# Can't get correct Key-Value Pairs with Tika

Tags: java, apache, metadata, key-value, apache-tika

I'm trying to get the Metadata Values from an Office Document and all it shows as key-value pair is this one:

Content-Type: application/zip

I just can't tell the issue in this one. Why does it only show the Content-Type?
What i'm interested in are Keys like title.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class App 
{
    private static final String PATH = "C:/docs/myDocument.docx";


    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException
    {


        Metadata metadata = new Metadata(); 
        AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(PATH);
        BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
        parser.parse(fileStream, handler, metadata);

        String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();

        for (String key : metadataNames) {
            String value = metadata.get(key);

            System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My hunch is that you're missing the Tika Parsers jar, or one of the dependencies of it. How are you adding Apache Tika's jars to your project?

Comment: @Gagravarr i'm using maven and got 2 dependencies inside my pom `org.apache.tika` 0.2 and `org.apache.tika.tika-parsers` 0.6.
Maybe i should replace them with other versions...

Comment: @Gagravarr Okay so the `org.apache.tika` interfered somehow with the parser and after removing it everything was working as intended. Thx for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer - you appear to be missing some key Apache Tika jars or their dependencies.

If you're using Maven, then your pom should have (as of January 2015) should have something like:

```
<properties>
  <tika.version>1.7</tika.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
    <version>${tika.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
    <version>${tika.version}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The `tika-core` artifact gives you everything you need to run Tika, and develop your own parsers, but doesn't come with any parsers. It's the `tika-parsers` artifact (+dependencies!) which provides all the built-in Tika parsers, which you need to process files liek yours

Comment: Thx for the Answer that was exactly what was missing